# Stopping ladda spinner if invalid form fields are found

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, form-submit, ladda

I'm using the [ladda](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda) spinner in my button on my login page. I'm binding the button to the submit button, but the button doesn't stop if there is form field invalidation, like a bad password or missing password. It keeps spinning.

I know I can stop the ladda spinner by making a manual call like

```
ladda.stop()
```

but what kind of code do I need to catch for invalid form fields?

I tried

```
$("#myForm").submit(...)
```

but it never gets called if there is an error in a field

Comment: yes but when would I use it? the question was when, not how

Comment: tried that, look at my post! It doesn't get called if the fields fail

Comment: Are you using jQuery Validate plugin as indicated by your tag?  If so, then show your call to the `.validate()` method... otherwise, we're just guessing here.  Where is the relevant markup?  Maybe look at the jQuery Validate docs too:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. 
    ladda.stop() 
 will not work. You have to initialise the ladda button. use this snippet it will work

```
var l = Ladda.create( document.querySelector( 'button[type=submit]' ) );
 $('.ladda-button').on('click',function(e){
      var form = $(this).closest('form')[0];
      if(form.checkValidity() == true) {
          l.start();
          form.submit();
      } else{
          l.stop();
      }
  });
```